# Comparing 2 attribute tables to discern unmatched attributes

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In QGIS, I am trying to compare two different attribute tables. One is simply the updated version of the other. Each feature has a unique identifier.

How can I return the number of unmatched records? Is it possible to compare two separate attribute tables in QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like a quick hack than a proper solution:

- joint the smaller file (with less features) to the larger one (using
  your common unique identifier)
- select "keep all records"
- open the joined attribute table and count all features with NULL values